# List in pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
    | A |    B   |
    | :-|:------:|
    | 1 | [2,3,4]|
    | 2 | np.nan |
    | 3 | np.nan | 
    | 4 |   10   |
```

I would like to unlist the first row and place those values sequentially in the subsequent rows. The outcome will look like this:

```
    | A |    B   |
    | :-|:------:|
    | 1 |    2   |
    | 2 |    3   |
    | 3 |    4   | 
    | 4 |   10   |
```

How can I achieve this in a very large dataset with this phenomena occurring in many rows?

Comment: Are there always n-1 Nan following a list of length n? If not, what should happen?

Comment: In the original data almost always there is more Nan values ( > n ) than the list of length n.

Comment: Ok and so what should happen when there are more NaNs? Also, almost always is not always, is it possible to have less NaN?

Comment: No, I rechecked. I think it is not possible to have less NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the number of consecutive NaNs does not match the length of the list, you can make groups starting with non NaN elements and `explode` while keeping the length of the group constant.

I used a slightly different example for clarity (I also assigned to a different column):

```
df['C'] = (df['B']
   .groupby(df['B'].notna().cumsum())
   .apply(lambda s: s.explode().iloc[:len(s)])
   .values
 )
```

Output:

```
   A          B    C
0  1  [2, 3, 4]    2
1  2        NaN    3
2  3        NaN    4
3  4        NaN  NaN
4  5         10   10
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1,6),
                   'B': [[2,3,4], np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 10]
                  })
```

Answer (score 3):

If the number of NaN values serve as a "slack" space, so that list elements can slot in, i.e. if the lengths match, then you can `explode` columns "B", then drop NaN values with `dropna`, reset index and assign back to "B":

```
df['B'] = df['B'].explode().dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   A   B
0  1   2
1  2   3
2  3   4
3  4  10
```